# How can I add custom requirement to buildozer.spec file

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer, kivymd

My buildozer.spec file looks like this.

```
requirements = python3, mysql-connector-python, plyer, android, futures, datetime,kivy, kivymd
```

I want to use development version of kivymd so I changed that to something like this:

```
requirements = python3, mysql-connector-python, plyer, android, futures, datetime, https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip
```

But it doesn't seams to work. It crashes immediately.
I tried also this one:

```
requirements = python3, mysql-connector-python, plyer, android, futures, datetime, kivy, https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip
```

but I've got the same result.

What is the correct way to change the requirements?
Or maybe I can download and add it somehow locally?

EDIT:
I've realise that i can use option `requirements.source` so i did this:

```
requirements = python3, mysql-connector-python, plyer, android, futures, datetime, kivy, kivymd

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
requirements.source.kivymd = /home/sylwek/buildozer_Test1/KivyMD-master
```

But it still doesn't work...

Comment: What you put on the requirements line is passed to pip if not available as a recipe, so you need to write whatever pip expects to install a github repository. If that doesn't work, the problem is likely elsewhere and you need to read the error to debug it.

Comment: It gives me error at first import using kivymd. So obviosly the problem is there. Mayby is there some way to do 'https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip as kivymd'  or something like this.

Comment: I even tried pasting kivymd files to my app folder. But it still doesnt work but it still gives me "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivymd'"

Comment: Having the error at import doesn't mean the problem is there, it means any one of many different failures have happened to prevent the import. It could have failed to build/include kivymd at all.

Comment: What should I do with that? When I install this repository on my pc it works perfectly( pip install https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip) but here it has problems.

Comment: Debug the problem. Read the errors and try to understand what they mean. Ask about them if you can't work it out.

Answer (score 0):

I've kind a pushed through the problem. I debugged test app with this configuration:
`requirements = python3,kivy==2.0.0rc4,kivymd, pillow`
and after debugging (i've tested for sure that it works).
I've edited by hand this folder: `/Documents/my_project/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivymd`
with files from version I want. Debugged it again and tested it with simple script:

```py
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
import kivymd

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return MDLabel(text=f"kivymd version: {kivymd.__version__}", halign="center")

MainApp().run()
```

And surprisingly it worked...
I know it's not the best solution, but it works ;).